# Add a design element to my .aspx website

Tags: html, image, slideshow

[microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)

[kavos-aparatai.lt](http://www.kavos-aparatai.lt/)

These websites have an element on the top of there pages that slideshow images and that are hyper linked. How can I make something like this in my Visual Studio?

Comment: Go to http://getcu3er.com/

Comment: I'm figuring this out at the moment, anyone has other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.designresourcebox.com/nivo-jquery-slider/) is a very good image slider that you can use. (Not necessary, you can search for more in google). Simply put hyper link around your image tag

```
<a href="google.com"><img src="path to image" /></a>
```